How can I get each of my objects to "bounce" off one another when they collide?
Here is my program that has a run method which runs the simulation.
import java.util.*;
public class Game{
    public static int size;
    public int numObjects;
    public static int speedX;
    public static int speedY;
    ArrayList<Rock> rockArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Paper> paperArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Scissors> scissorsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public Game(int size, int numObjects, int speedX, int speedY){
        Game.size = size;
        Game.speedX = speedX;
        Game.speedY = speedY;
        this.numObjects = numObjects;
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(size, size); //set up drawing canvas
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, size);        //<0, 0> is bottom left.  <size-1, size-1> is top right
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, size);

        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i<numObjects; i++) {
            int neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedX *= ((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int x = random.nextInt(size);

            neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedY*=((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int y = random.nextInt(size);

            rockArrayList.add(new Rock(x,y,speedX, speedY));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<numObjects; i++) {
            int neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedX *= ((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int x = random.nextInt(size);

            neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedY*=((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int y = random.nextInt(size);
            paperArrayList.add(new Paper(x,y,speedX,speedY));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<numObjects; i++) {
            int neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedX *= ((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int x = random.nextInt(size);

            neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedY*=((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int y = random.nextInt(size);
            scissorsArrayList.add(new Scissors(x,y,speedX,speedY));
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true){
            StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.BLACK);

            StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();

            for(Rock r : rockArrayList) {
                r.update();
            }

            for(Paper p : paperArrayList) {
                p.update();
            }

            for(Scissors s : scissorsArrayList) {
                s.update();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < paperArrayList.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < rockArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    if(paperArrayList.get(i).doesCollideWith(rockArrayList.get(j))) {
                        paperArrayList.add(new Paper(rockArrayList.get(j).getX(), rockArrayList.get(j).getY(),speedX,speedY));
                        paperArrayList.get(paperArrayList.size()-1).changeSpeedX(-1);
                        rockArrayList.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < rockArrayList.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < scissorsArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    if(rockArrayList.get(i).doesCollideWith(scissorsArrayList.get(j))) {
                        rockArrayList.add(new Rock(scissorsArrayList.get(j).getX(), scissorsArrayList.get(j).getY(),speedX,speedY));
                        rockArrayList.get(rockArrayList.size()-1).changeSpeedY(-1);
                        scissorsArrayList.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < scissorsArrayList.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < paperArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    if(scissorsArrayList.get(i).doesCollideWith(paperArrayList.get(j))) {
                        scissorsArrayList.add(new Scissors(paperArrayList.get(j).getX(), paperArrayList.get(j).getY(),speedX,speedY));
                        scissorsArrayList.get(scissorsArrayList.size()-1).changeSpeedY(-1);
                        paperArrayList.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            if((rockArrayList.isEmpty() && paperArrayList.isEmpty()) || (rockArrayList.isEmpty() && scissorsArrayList.isEmpty()) || (paperArrayList.isEmpty() && scissorsArrayList.isEmpty()) )
                break;

            for(Rock r : rockArrayList)
                r.draw();

            for(Paper p : paperArrayList)
                p.draw();

            for(Scissors s : scissorsArrayList)
                s.draw();

            StdDraw.show();
            StdDraw.pause(20);
        }
    }
}

Here rock, paper, and scissors are all objects (I should have probably made a superclass) that are simulated to spawn in a bounce until one of them "wins". Here is the constructor for them (they are all the same except the name) :
public Rock(int x, int y, int speedX, int speedY){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
}

There is a update method in each of the objects which help the object stay on the screen:
public void update(){
    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;
    if(x+speedX >= Game.size || x+speedX<=0)
        speedX *= -1;
    if(y+speedY >= Game.size || y+speedY<=0)
        speedY*=-1;
}

Lastly I have a interface called Collideable which checks if one object collides with another (the implementing of this method is same in all 3 classes)
@Override
public boolean doesCollideWith(Collideable collideable){
    if(Math.abs(collideable.getX()-this.x)<10){
        return Math.abs(collideable.getY() - this.y) < 10;
    }
    return false;
}

As you can see in my run method I want a way to make each object bounce off each other without making the time complexity of this program exceed O(n^2). Essentially I want to stop using so many loops to check something that could be done in a more concise way. For all the graphical stuff I am using Princeton's StdDraw class.
I have tried to use a triple nested for loop to check but it looks like a huge mess and I fell too ashamed to share it because the terrible quality of the code. I'm not 100% sure but I think it might be easier to use a different data structure and not a Arraylist but I am not currently aware of any such other data structure.
Here are all the classes in the program:
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Game game = new Game(900,100, 3,3);
       game.run();
   }
}

import java.util.*;

public class Game{
    public static int size;
    public int numObjects;
    public static int speedX;
    public static int speedY;
    ArrayList<Rock> rockArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Paper> paperArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Scissors> scissorsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public Game(int size, int numObjects, int speedX, int speedY){
        Game.size = size;
        Game.speedX = speedX;
        Game.speedY = speedY;
        this.numObjects = numObjects;
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(size, size); //set up drawing canvas
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, size);        //<0, 0> is bottom left.  <size-1, size-1> is top right
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, size);

        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i<numObjects; i++) {
            int neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedX *= ((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int x = random.nextInt(size);

            neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedY*=((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int y = random.nextInt(size);

            rockArrayList.add(new Rock(x,y,speedX, speedY));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<numObjects; i++) {
            int neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedX *= ((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int x = random.nextInt(size);

            neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedY*=((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int y = random.nextInt(size);
            paperArrayList.add(new Paper(x,y,speedX,speedY));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<numObjects; i++) {
            int neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedX *= ((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int x = random.nextInt(size);

            neg = random.nextInt(2);
            speedY*=((neg == 0) ? 1:-1);
            int y = random.nextInt(size);
            scissorsArrayList.add(new Scissors(x,y,speedX,speedY));
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true){
            StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.BLACK);

            StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();

            for(Rock r : rockArrayList) {
                r.update();
            }

            for(Paper p : paperArrayList) {
                p.update();
            }

            for(Scissors s : scissorsArrayList) {
                s.update();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < paperArrayList.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < rockArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    if(paperArrayList.get(i).doesCollideWith(rockArrayList.get(j))) {
                        paperArrayList.add(new Paper(rockArrayList.get(j).getX(), rockArrayList.get(j).getY(),speedX,speedY));
                        paperArrayList.get(paperArrayList.size()-1).changeSpeedX(-1);
                        rockArrayList.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < rockArrayList.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < scissorsArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    if(rockArrayList.get(i).doesCollideWith(scissorsArrayList.get(j))) {
                        rockArrayList.add(new Rock(scissorsArrayList.get(j).getX(), scissorsArrayList.get(j).getY(),speedX,speedY));
                        rockArrayList.get(rockArrayList.size()-1).changeSpeedY(-1);
                        scissorsArrayList.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < scissorsArrayList.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < paperArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    if(scissorsArrayList.get(i).doesCollideWith(paperArrayList.get(j))) {
                        scissorsArrayList.add(new Scissors(paperArrayList.get(j).getX(), paperArrayList.get(j).getY(),speedX,speedY));
                        scissorsArrayList.get(scissorsArrayList.size()-1).changeSpeedY(-1);
                        paperArrayList.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            if((rockArrayList.isEmpty() && paperArrayList.isEmpty()) || (rockArrayList.isEmpty() && scissorsArrayList.isEmpty()) || (paperArrayList.isEmpty() && scissorsArrayList.isEmpty()) )
                break;

            for(Rock r : rockArrayList)
                r.draw();

            for(Paper p : paperArrayList)
                p.draw();

            for(Scissors s : scissorsArrayList)
                s.draw();

            StdDraw.show();
            StdDraw.pause(20);
        }
    }
}

public class Rock implements Collideable {
    int x;
    int y;
    int speedX;
    int speedY;
    public Rock(int x, int y, int speedX, int speedY){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }
    public void draw(){
        StdDraw.picture(x,y,"res/rock.png", 20, 20);
    }

    public void update(){
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;
        if(x+speedX >= Game.size || x+speedX<=0)
            speedX *= -1;
        if(y+speedY >= Game.size || y+speedY<=0)
            speedY*=-1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void changeSpeedX(int speedX){
        this.speedX *= speedX;
    }

    public void changeSpeedY(int speedY){
        this.speedY *= speedY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doesCollideWith(Collideable collideable){
        if(Math.abs(collideable.getX()-this.x)<10){
            return Math.abs(collideable.getY() - this.y) < 10;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Paper implements Collideable {
    int x;
    int y;
    int speedX;
    int speedY;
    public Paper(int x, int y, int speedX, int speedY){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }
    public void draw(){
        StdDraw.picture(x,y,"res/paper.png",20,20);
    }

    public void update(){
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;
        if(x+speedX >= Game.size || x+speedX<=0)
            speedX *= -1;
        if(y+speedY >= Game.size || y+speedY<=0)
            speedY*=-1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void changeSpeedX(int speedX){
        this.speedX *= speedX;
    }

    public void changeSpeedY(int speedY){
        this.speedY *= speedY;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean doesCollideWith(Collideable collideable){
        if(Math.abs(collideable.getX()-this.x)<10){
            return Math.abs(collideable.getY() - this.y) < 10;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Scissors implements Collideable {
    int x;
    int y;
    int speedX;
    int speedY;
    public Scissors(int x, int y, int speedX, int speedY){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }
    public void draw(){
        StdDraw.picture(x,y,"res/scissors.png",20,20);
    }

    public void update(){
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;
        if(x+speedX >= Game.size || x+speedX<=0)
            speedX *= -1;
        if(y+speedY >= Game.size || y+speedY<=0)
            speedY*=-1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void changeSpeedX(int speedX){
        this.speedX *= speedX;
    }

    public void changeSpeedY(int speedY){
        this.speedY *= speedY;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean doesCollideWith(Collideable collideable){
        if(Math.abs(collideable.getX()-this.x)<10){
            return Math.abs(collideable.getY() - this.y) < 10;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public interface Collideable {
    public boolean doesCollideWith(Collideable collideable);
    public int getX();
    public int getY();
}


This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

@SimonC Unless the user is willing to share the code they are currently hiding, this question does not belong on Code Review. Code Review does not answer How to ... questions.

Yes i can provide all the remain code I just thought it was unnecessary

So, #1, it is a lot more efficient to use .contains() in a HashSet than in an ArrayList (O(1) vs O(n)). Therefore, you should make use of a HashSet (Or possibly TreeSet, you can learn more about these on oracle or smth) to keep track of their locations.
Then, use pairs(read on these too) to store the data, and take your set of rocks (Let's say if you were currently checking scissor and rock collisions) and check if each scissor's coordinate Pair is contained in the HashSet or not. Taking these coordinates, you can then change every rock/paper at these coordinates. You can repeat this process for the other checks.
Because you want to check when the objects are within a distance of the coordinates, you'd probably have to divide all the coordinates by 10 or however much you want your radius to be, and you'd probably want to do this initially to all the coordinates you add to the Sets that contain the rocks/papers/scissors to avoid annoyances in the future. You'll probably have to change up your code a lot, but this is the way I think would work.
Don't use a HashMap, use a HashSet. Search up the documentation online, but just as a general starter, a HashSet is a non-repeating collection of variables with no indices. A few functions are .add(), .contains(), which are exactly what they sound like.

Right that is what I'm asking how can I use a HashMap or a TreeSet I have provided my code I was looking for a answer that could be used. I am aware of the concept but im just stuck on this part of the problem.
